# Angular Date Pipe skip optional parameter format while providing timezone

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I need to supply the timezone (+0000) to the Date pipe since i am using UTC timestamps as following:

```
 | date:'dd.MM.yyyy':'+0000'
```

Since America is using "MM.dd.yyyy" i would like to not specify the `format` pipe argument.

I Tried supplying false, null and 0 but those break the pipe.

how can i skip optional parameters in angular pipes or specifically the date pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just supply undefined as argument:

```
(dateVariable  | date:undefined:'+0000'
```